# wxWidgets Socket Transfer Rate

Tags: c++, sockets, wxwidgets

What is the best way to figure out the transfer rate of a wxWidgets socket. Is there a built in way to do this, or would I be better getting the time before a transfer of data and then after its done and comparing them?

I ask because I want to be able to limit the transfer rate of my sockets to a user entered value.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

No, there does not appear to be any mechanism built into wxWidgets to measure socket transfer rate [*](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.9.2/classwx_socket_client-members.html). The best you can do is to measure the rate at which you call [`wxSocketBase::Write`](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.9.2/classwx_socket_base.html#7676f1821d2e17db95de2438346355cd).

Note that this won't be perfectly accurate, however. Just because you write to a socket doesn't mean that the data is already sent, much less already received.